# Using php information in jQuery

Tags: php, jquery

I am trying to get a variable from the php code and put it in jquery i have tryed this and it does not work can anyone help me?

```
< script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.query-2.1.6.js"></script>
<?
$next_exp = 123;
?>



 $(document).ready(function() {
 var next_exp = $.query.get('next_exp');
 $("#pb5").progressBar({ max: next_exp, textFormat: 'fraction',barImage: 'images/progressbg_orange.gif' });
```

});

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need to encode non-scalar values (such as arrays, objects or just about anything), you can use `json_encode()`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    <?php
        $next_exp = array(1, 2, 3);
        echo 'var next_exp = ' . json_encode($next_exp);
    ?>
    // next_exp is now a usable JavaScript array: [1, 2, 3]
</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

Anywhere you want to use the PHP $next_exp, you need to do

```
<?=$next_exp ?>
```

if short tags are enabled, or

```
<?php echo $next_exp; ?>
```

if short tags are disabled.

Answer (score 4):

You need to set a javascript variable form the PHP variable first:

```
<?
echo("<script>");
echo("var next_exp=$next_exp");
echo("</script>");
?>
```

Then you will be able to use it in your Javascript. So your whole example would look like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.query-2.1.6.js"></script>
<?
    echo("<script type='text/javascript'>");
    echo("var next_exp=$next_exp");
    echo("</script>");
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#pb5").progressBar({ max: next_exp, textFormat: 'fraction',barImage: 'images/progressbg_orange.gif' });
</script>
```